# Как можно вызвать "emergency restart" через Win32 API?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, windows-11

Emergency restart - функция в Windows 10/11. В отличии от обычной перезагрузки, emergency restart убивает все службы и программы, не дожидаясь их завершения. Обычная перезагрузка закрывает все программы и выключает службы, что требует времени.

Я задался вопросом, как эту перезагрузку вызвать из Win32 API?

Я проверял документацию от Microsoft, но там задокументирована только обычная перезагрузка.

Вызвать её можно, нажав CTRL ALT DELETE и нажать на кнопку выключения, **задерживая клавишу CTRL**. Появится окно, которое запрашивает подтверждение, говорит, что это нужно использовать как "последнюю меру".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex
Там есть флаг `EWX_FORCE`